# Conditional Probability: Find the probability that the other drawer has a silver coin.

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Suppose we have four chests each having two drawers. Chests 1 and 2
have a gold coin in one drawer and a silver coin in the other drawer.
Chest 3 has two gold coins and chest 4 has two silver coins. A chest is
selected at random and a drawer opened. It is found to contain a gold
coin.

**Find the probability that the other drawer has a silver coin.**

I'm not sure how to solve this problem, here is what I tried:

(1)

$A:$select a chest that contains at least one gold coin.

$B$: select a chest that contains at least one silver coin.

So $P(A) = \frac{3}{4}$ and $P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}$

Then $P(B\mid A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{2}{3}$

(2)

$A_{1}, A_{2},A_{3},A_{4}:$ selecting a chest.

$B:$ finding a silver coin

Then $P(A_{i})=\frac{1}{4}$ for $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$

$P(B\mid A_{1})=\frac{1}{2}$,
$P(B\mid A_{2})=\frac{1}{2}$,
$P(B\mid A_{3})=0$,
$P(B\mid A_{4})=1$

So I need to calculate: $P(A_{1}\mid B) \cup P(A_{2}\mid B)$

$P(A_{1}\mid B) \cup P(A_{2}\mid B)=P(A_{1}\mid B)+P(A_{2}\mid B)$

$=\frac{P(A_{1})P(B\mid A_{1})}{\sum_{k=1}^{4} P(A_{k})P(B\mid A_{k})}+\frac{P(A_{2})P(B\mid A_{2})}{\sum_{k=1}^{4} P(A_{k})P(B\mid A_{k})}=\frac{1}{2}$

I don't know if any of this is correct, any help thanks

Comment: I think is incorrect because P(A)+P(B)-P(AnB) is 1/2, but P(AuB)=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the event of choosing chest 1 or 2.

Let $B$ denote the event of drawing a gold coin.

Then $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{2}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{0}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an informal way to think about it if you are just looking for the answer.

Draw out the tree of the 8 possible outcomes.  Level one branches into the 4 dressers and then level 2 is each dresser branching into the 2 drawers.  For 8 final endpoints.  Importantly, all 8 of these are equally likely to be chosen.

Now, inspect the 4 that are gold coins and find the probability that they were from a dresser that also has a silver coin and you will find it is $\frac{2}{4}$.

Comment: +1.  I would have shortened this to *"There are $4$ equally probable drawers with a gold coin. In $2$ of these cases, their partner drawer has a silver coin."*